# Transition for scikit learn to xgboost: Where can I find a comprehensive documentation for xgboost? (Python)

Tags: python, boosting

As the internet seems to be conviced that xgboost is well worth a shot when working with decision trees anyways, I set out to try it. I deal with a binary classification problem.

Up to now, I was working with the scikit learn library and I always refered to the respective documentation; e.g. [gradient boosting](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html). It tells me which input parameters I can use and which methods I can apply.

Is there something comprehensive like this available for xgboost as well? I found which [input parameters](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html) I can use, but not which methods can be applied.

What I've tired (and what worked surprisingly well) was simply using the methods I was using with the scikit learn gradient boosting classifier:

```py
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = my_data
y = my_data_target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

xgbm = xgb.XGBClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)

xgbm_accTrain = xgbm.score(X_train, y_train)
xgbm_acc = xgbm.score(X_test, y_test)
xgbm_pred = xgbm.predict(X_test)
xgbm_predProb = xgbm.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]

i = ["Gradient Boost", xgbm_accTrain, xgbm_acc, xgbm_pred, xgbm_predProb]

av_pres = average_precision_score(y_test, i[4]) #calculated before as it will be needed more often
print(
    "{:<33} {:5.03f}".format("Accuracy (training):", i[1]),
    "{:<33} {:5.03f}".format("Accuracy:", i[2]),
    "{:<33} {:5.03f}".format("F-score:", f1_score(y_test, i[3])),
    "{:<33} {:5.03f}".format("Precision:", precision_score(y_test, i[3])),
    "{:<33} {:5.03f}".format("Recall:", recall_score(y_test, i[3])),
    "{:<33} {:5.03f}".format("Average precision (PR-curve):", av_pres),
    "{:<33} {:5.03f}".format("AUC (ROC-curve):", roc_auc_score(y_test, i[4])),
    sep="\n"
)
```

[image]

Can I do this? The results seem reasonable, but I want to be sure.

One more thing: Several xgboost tutorials use a `DMatrix` (This [iris classification](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/03/simple-xgboost-tutorial-iris-dataset.html), for instance). Why? I mean, it worked for me without it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something comprehensive like this available for xgboost as well?

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/

> What I've tired (and what worked surprisingly well) was simply using the methods I was using with the scikit learn gradient boosting classifier. Can I do this?

Yes. Is there something particularly that you're worried about?

> Several `xgboost` tutorials use a `DMatrix` (This iris classification, for instance). Why?

The `DMatrix` is a specialized data type that's optimized for use in estimating an xgboost model. Specialized loaders exist to read data directly into the `DMatrix` format. You might find that it is more expedient than using `numpy` or `pandas` types if all of your use case is covered by the more limited `DMatrix` functionality.